# Is there a way to check function signature before calling it?

Tags: c++, function, signature

for example this works:

```
if ( typeid( int) == typeid( int) ) //...
```

how to do the same with function signatures?

```
if (typeid (void (*)(void) ) == typeid( void(*)(void) ) //that of course dosn't work
```

how do we check thos two for signature?

```
void f(int);
int x(double);
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for a solution without a problem.

Comment: Why would want to? At runtime I see no use as the decision has been made by yhe linker already - seems like you may be trying something that there is an alternative solution to it.

Comment: @Ignacio I think the problem is posted

Comment: No, *a question* is posted. There is a difference.

Comment: @codekiddy - when two professional programers ask why you trying to do something - there is probably a good reason. ie they both think you a making a mistake with your approach. More information in the question on why you think this is a solution may actually help people guide you to the correct solution to your actual problem. We are both sure that what you are trying to do is not a good solution to your actual problem

Comment: thanks, I'll try to remeber that.

Comment: @codekiddy, why did you say "//that of course dosn't work" ? It does work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `typeid(foo).name()` .

For instance : `if ( typeid(func1).name() == typeid(func2).name() )`  //do stuff

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std ;

void foo()
{    
}

int bar()
{   
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
   if (typeid(foo).name() == typeid(bar).name())
       cout<<typeid(foo).name()<<" equals "<<typeid(bar).name()<<" \n";
   else
   if (typeid(foo).name() != typeid(bar).name())
       cout<<typeid(foo).name()<<" is not equal to "<<typeid(bar).name()<<" \n";

   cout << "\nPress ENTER to continue \n\n";   cin.ignore();  // pause screen

   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
void (__cdecl*)(void) is not equal to int (__cdecl*)(void)
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of a function is known at compile-time.  You can compare arbitrary types using `is_same`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    typedef void(*F0)(int);
    typedef void(*F1)(int, int);

    std::cout << std::is_same<F0, F0>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<F0, F1>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
1
0
```

The type trait value is a compile-time constant and can be used in template instantiation and for SFINAE.

Comment: I have no idea how this information would be useful at runtime.  Certainly it has many uses at compile-time.

Comment: that's interesting, I didn't know that function signature can't be determined at run time so thsi help in some way, for debuging maybe. thanks!